# Audio file in homepage

Tags: php, css, html

I need to add an audio file to my homepage, but I need that the audio doesn't stop when I move to another title/page. I need that this audio .mp3 file is playing in the background. I'm working with Microsoft Expression Web 4. Can you help me? Thanks!!!

This is what I've used now:

```
<audio id="myAudio"
 <source src="audiofile.mp3"
         type='audio/mp3'>
 <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/07/bunny/04-Death_Becomes_Fur.oga"
         type='audio/ogg; codecs=vorbis'>
 Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Audio element.
</audio>
<button type="button" onclick="aud_play_pause()" style="width: 296px; height: 35px">
<span class="auto-style1">
<strong>If you want to listen - click this!</strong></span></button>
<script>
function aud_play_pause() {
  var myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
  if (myAudio.paused) {
    myAudio.play();
  } else {
    myAudio.pause();
  }
```

}

I put it in the .php file I use to navigate. At this point I'm not sure if it's the correct code or even in the correct place!

Comment: you can use live radio station. In that you can upload your own audio which you want play

Comment: I added my code and where I put it. I don't know what is live radio station. Can you direct me to some example/documentation?

Comment: this will cause to performance of your site. Use on-line radio station. That helps you like YouTube. check this link http://www.radiotunes.com

Answer (score 1):

try this  :

```
<audio src="/music/your_file.mp3" autoplay>
<p>If you are reading this, it is because your browser does not support the audio element.     </p>
<embed src="/music/your_file.mp3" width="180" height="90" hidden="true" />
</audio>
```

> UPDATE

if you navigate to another pages it will stop the track and it will start again on the new page.

There are three ways to make the track playing continuously in the all pages  :

- open your audio player in a popup
- frames
- Change the page content dynamical with Javascript without reloading the page

Comment: I added code to my question - I think your example is just about what I do, but the file doesn't KEEP on playing on new page, it just stops and has to be manually started up again.

Comment: popup seems best option, could you direct me to an example, please?

Comment: you can simply do it by Window open() Method, Please check this link : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use the following codes:

```
<embed src="filename.extension" autostart="true" loop="true"
width="0" height="0">
</embed>
<noembed><bgsound src="filename.extension" loop="infinite"></noembed>
```

Its working here...